# Using different wordpress loop output depending on category

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a somewhat advanced wordpress loop for a new website. I would like to display all recent posts on the front page, but differently depending on chosen category.

I am thinking something like this:

```
Start Loop

Check if category = category 1

If category = category 1:

<-- Loop elements for said category (template tags etc.) -->

Else, check if category = category 2

If category = category 2 

<-- Loop elements for said category (template tags etc.) -->

Else

<-- Standard loop elements (template tags etc.) -->

End loop
```

Is this possible? Are there simpler ways to do this? I realize i could use multiple loops, but would like to keep the posts in chronological order.

I tried using the following code, but this breaks when i put the template tags in the echo?

```
<?php
$category_name = 'Category 1';
if(in_category($category_name)) {
  echo '

<div class="post">
the_title();
the_excerpt();
<div>

';
}
?>
```

Any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<?php
$category_name = 'Category 1';
if(in_category($category_name)) {
?>

<div class="post">
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems to work ok, but it breaks when i try to add another category? What is the correct way to do so?